# How to trigger a backbone keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, karma-jasmine, marionette

I am trying to test a backbone/marionette application using jasmine,

I am trying to trigger an 'keyup' event and expecting a method to be called. but when i try to trigger an even like so after instantiating the View, it doesnt work, even though it is able to find the title class

i tried to trigger keyup event in Jasmine like this

```
view.$el.find('.title').trigger('keyup');
```

this is the View event that I have defined

```
  events: {
    'keyup .title': 'onKeyUpToggleOfferDetails',
  },
```

Comment: Please share an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery [keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) method like `view.$el.find('.title').keyup();`